# adding a project from GitHub

Tags: android

i am trying to add this project "https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview" into my project. I tried to add it to my workspace as a lib project but eclipse wont let me add the folder to my workspace.

Comment: You can click clone to desktop or download zip and then import it from your dowmloaded location. One of the options. There is also the import from git option, but it sounds like that may have given you some issues.

Comment: It's not an Eclipse project, it's an Android Studio project.

Comment: @JustinJasmann- so how can i add this to my project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know, how to build Android Applications with the **Gradle** build tool. This needs some Prerequisites such as **Apache Ant** and **Gradle**.

Here is a good toutorial - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html

Before importing the library, complete an example using gradle. Then surely you'll know, how to do this one.